Replace text in multiple files with different strings
I've been looking at another text replace batch script and tried to tweak it but syntax is wrong and couldn't find how it should be structured.
Hopefully someone can make this possible or tell me if it won't work.
There are a number of text files they will be named xxxxx with individual numbers on the end so *601.txt, *602.txt, etc.
They will have multiple lines in the file that are LIVEEVENT but depending on the file i would like to replace with LIVEEVENTxxx so for xxxx601 it should update to LIVEEVENT601.
Here is what I have that isn't working, obviously I can make it work fine for one variable ignoring the rest so i suspect its the way the separate for commands are set up or if this is even possible to split out.
Ideally I'd like to echo off depending on if the file is found and the event is changed. You can probably work out the jist from the script but formatting will be completely wrong.
@echo off 
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

echo Copying Files....

xcopy "C:xxxx\INPUT\*.txt" "C:xxxx\OUTPUT\"

TIMEOUT /T 2

echo Setting Variables....

set "search=LIVEEVENT"
set "replace01=LIVEEVENT601"
set "replace02=LIVEEVENT602"
set "textFile01=*601.txt"
set "textFile02=*602.txt"
set "rootDir=.\OUTPUT"

if %textFile01% echo 601 Found!

do (
for /R "%rootDir%" %%j in ("%textFile01%") do (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~j" ^& break ^> "%%~j"') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace01%!"
        >>"%%~j" echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)
    
if %textFile02% echo 601 Found!

do (
for /R "%rootDir%" %%j in ("%textFile02%") do (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~j" ^& break ^> "%%~j"') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace02%!"
        >>"%%~j" echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)       
    
echo 601 line updated!

endlocal

@pause  


You can extract the number from the filename (assuming three-digit numbers as in your examples).
Get a list of your files and process each of them (without knowing beforehand how many there are and what the numbers are), extract the number and call a subroutine to replace the string in one file:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM following `for` to generate some testfiles:
for /L %%i in (601,1,620) do (
  echo LIVEEVENT>test%%i.txt
)
REM simulate an already processed file:
echo LIVEEVENT610>test610.txt


set "search=LIVEEVENT"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b test*.txt') do (
  set "fnam=%%~na"
  set "fnum=!fnam:~-3!"
  for %%b in ("%%a") do (
    call :replacement "%%a" !fnum!
  )
)
echo done.
goto :eof

:replacement  "filename" filenumber
findstr "%search%[0-9][0-9][0-9]" %1 >nul && (echo %1 already done. & goto :eof)
ECHO replace %search% with %search%%2 in file %~1...
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%~1" ^& break ^> "%~1"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%search%%2!"
    >>"%~1" echo(!line!
    endlocal
)

You should add some code to make sure you are not reprocessing an already processed file (it's the findstr line)
I completely ignored your for /R switch, as there is no hint in your question that you want to search in subfolders too. If you actually do, don't do a for /R, but expand the dir command accordingly: dir /b /s "test*.txt"
